# What's the right word for something that doesn't sum to 100%?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, synonyms

Suppose I have a pie chart with segments that don't sum to 100%.  Would I call this a "partial" pie chart?  An "incomplete" pie chart?  Is there a better word to use for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you should add one more small slice that makes it total 100%, label it as "other" or "remainders" and then call it a pie chart.

Comment: *Leftovers*. :)

Comment: Perhaps a pie chart is not the right choice to use to visualize the data.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to name the chart by the fraction of the pie being shown.  A [half pie chart](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/present-data-half-pie-chart-excel/) occurs when half the pie is used to represent data, like if the graphic is showing what would happen in the first six months of a year.

Otherwise, there is no standard term for this kind of chart. Instances of "[incomplete pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383257/creating-an-incomplete-pie-chart-in-dimple-js)" and "[partial pie chart](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/pie_charts/partial_pie.html)" exist. An *incomplete* pie chart sounds like it is unfinished. A *partial* chart is general enough in description that the partiality could be intentional.